# Can use RegEx to compare two captured groups

Tags: regex, logging

I have a log message that i want to match only if two captured groups are the same!
example

some date from source-ip=1.1.1.1 trying to send another data to the destination-ip=1.1.1.1 in addition to some date

So, i want to trigger if sip=dip it matches!?
Would it be possible using a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done via back-references.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Using "some date from source-ip=1.1.1.1 trying to send another data to the destination-ip=1.1.1.1 in addition to some date" as input:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*(\1)
```